# Error while deleting log files in IIS

Tags: windows, iis

I am facing space problem in my live server where a lot of websites are running in IIS. While trying to delete log files I am facing the problem:

> The Process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

I have tried a lot by stop services and also by end process of explorer.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below Command for Command Prompet will work

del c:inetpub\logs\LogFiles*.logs /s

It will delete all log files

Answer (score 2):

It is done by me. IIS needs to stop from IIS manager By stoping from services it is not working. So please every body stop it from IIS manager and try to hit following one command to del IIS Log files

write below code in cmd

```
del c:inetpub\logs\LogFiles\*.logs /s
```

OR

save following code using file extension .bat and run it as administrator

```
forfiles /p "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d -0
```

I am posting here answer of my post so any body from the world face that problem then he/she can easily find solution.